# определение цвета для графических методов и элементов

Tags: java

1. исследуя Java в интернете я заметил что цвет задают разными методами

   g2.setPaint(Color.BLUE);

   g2.fillRect(0,0,640,32);

   g2.setColor(Color.red);

   g2.drawOval(w/2-250,w/2-250,500,500);

как же на самом деле правильно или принято в java?

и 2. как сделать что бы переменная или метод принимали 16е значения цвета
как в стандартной палитре цветов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Все варианты правильны. Какой удобнее, такой и исползуйте
2. Color myColor = Color.decode("e15b12");

Comment: понял. только наверно "0xe15b12" на минуточку